# Call function of a class within a function in the function within the same class

Tags: php, class, function, codeigniter, call

From the function abc();
1. How do I call ‘function a within class A’? ($this->a(); returns error)? 
2. How do I access to public variable $bbb?

(- I know the structure is bad but ‘require_once’ part is dynamic etc…)

```
    class AAA extends CI_Controller 
    {
        public $bbb;

    function ccc ()
    {
    }

    function index ()
    {
        require_once '1.php';
    }
    }
```

// in 1.php

```
function abc ()
{
 // how do i call method a of Class A?
 $this->ccc(); // returns error - Using $this when not in object context in ...
$this->bbb; //
}

abc(); // etc etc
```

Comment: Why do you declare `$a` and `function a` with the same name? It is a bad practice.

Comment: this is a simplified example come on dude... ok I will change the names ;;;

Comment: are you calling `$this->a()` outside of class `A`?

Comment: I changed the names. Uriel... not outside of class AAA. function abc(); is within index(); which is within the class AAA. I just require_once code from external files. Wow it does look uselessly complicated...

Comment: Nesting function definitions is not a good idea... it's going to lead into all kinds of scope resolution issues and readability issues, and is never necessary

Comment: I know this is a bad looking design, but this isn't an ordinary php/mysql web project. I will have to rethink about the design... it's gotta dynamically require the code, and the require_code shouldn't be a class (for simplicity). I thought of using CI driver or library concept but the current solution was the simplest to manage the application. (with minimal code maintenance effort etc)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do something with `require()` which it is not designed to do, and doesn't work for.

> However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php which also also applies to `require()`.

`abc()` gets defined in the global scope and thus doesn't have the object context necessary to use `$this`.

Comment: When I run index() of class AAA I get 'Using $this when not in object context' error now. Without abc(); - (without $this->) I get 'Call to undefined function' error ;;

Comment: Because it's trying to call `abc()`, which is defined in the global scope.

Comment: with all due respect, how can I call ccc(); from abc();? (the answer is I cant call the function?) I'm a bit confused.

Comment: You can't do what you're doing with `require()`.

Comment: thanks. guess i'll have to rethink the solution. The problem is that required code is dynamic (over 100 codes and it's growing), and the required code is hardly in a standard format to group it as a class (or it would take ages to achieve it)

Comment: however, from the PHP manual you linked. According to 'Example #2 Including within functions', functions in '1.php' would have the scope of index() of class AAA. (not global scope) no?

Answer (score 1):

As amber mentioned `require` wont help here. Couldnt you just pass reference to the function?

```
function abc (&$ref)
{
  $ref->ccc();
  $ref->bbb;
}
```

require it outside of class normally ant then just call

```
function index ()
{
  abc($this);
}
```

not sure it will work, but worth a try i believe

Comment: thanks. I will look into pass by reference. (I'm not very familiar with it, and I can't understand your code above yet).